# python tkinter label widgit not appearing in window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am using tkinter and I am trying to make a Label widget which is not appearing. The line in which I create the label executes , however nothing shows up on the window.

```
from tkinter import * class const():
    def __init__(self,par):
        self.parent = par
        self.window = Toplevel()
        self.window.title("ZZ")
        self.window.geometry("200x250")
        self.window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.parent.quit)
        self.bnl = []
        self.count = 0
        self.dic = {1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '', 7: '', 8: '', 9: ''}
        self.lbl=Label(par, text="Begin",font=("Arial",64),fg="BLACK",bg="RED")
        self.lbl.grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan=3)
```

Comment: do you run mainloop()?

Comment: Yes, and the other widgets are working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

self.lbl=Label(par, text="Begin",font=("Arial",12),fg="BLACK")

this line had an error, instead the following line is working fine:

self.lbl=Label(self.window, text="Begin",font=("Arial",12),fg="BLACK")